# append method overwriting instead of adding to list

Tags: python

I'm 99% sure I'm using the right method

```
for date in meta_data:
    win_ratio_list = []
    games = 0
    wins = 0
    games += meta_data[date]['games']
    wins += meta_data[date]['wins']
    print('date .... ' + date)
    print('win .... ' + str(wins))
    print('games .... ' + str(games))
    win_ratio = wins / games
    print('win ratio .... ' + str(win_ratio))
    print('\n\n')
    win_ratio_list.append(win_ratio)
    print(win_ratio_list)
```

The print statements verified that the correct win ratio is calculated through each loop and I verified in the Variable explorer in my IDE that the correct value for win_ratio is being written to win_ratio_list...it's just being overwritten each time.

Comment: swap lines one and two around

Comment: Whoops. There it was. Thanks